# Could not import vxlapi: function 'xlCanReceive' not found

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

I was trying to compile a code which interfaces with Cancasexl to send and receive signals from ECU. The library which I am using is python-can.

But I am getting an error which says:

```py
Could not import vxlapi: function 'xlCanReceive' not found

raise ImportError("The Vector API has not been loaded")
ImportError: The Vector API has not been loaded
```

I tried updating the CancaseXL drivers from the vector website thinking it might be a driver issue but still it shows up.

```py
def Can_receive_all(self):
  bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', channel=self.ch_list, bitrate=500000, app_name=self.can_app_name)
  try:
     while True:
        recv_msg = bus.recv()
        print(recv_msg)
      # if recv_msg is not None:
      # self.print_can_data(recv_msg)
   except Exception as ex:
     print(ex)
```

I expected the Rx signals from the ECU but getting an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the error message you receive

Comment: raise ImportError("The Vector API has not been loaded")
ImportError: The Vector API has not been loaded

Answer (score 0):

When reading the Python-CAN [documentation](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.1/interfaces/vector.html), it appears that you must have the Vector Hardware Config program in order to use the CANCase with Python-CAN. The documentation states the following :

```
Vector
This interface adds support for CAN controllers by Vector.

By default this library uses the channel configuration for CANalyzer. To use a 
different application, open Vector Hardware Config program and create a new 
application and assign the channels you may want to use. Specify the application name 
as app_name='Your app name' when constructing the bus or in a config file.

Channel should be given as a list of channels starting at 0.

Here is an example configuration file connecting to CAN 1 and CAN 2 for an 
application named “python-can”:

[default]
interface = vector
channel = 0, 1
app_name = python-can
```

Comment: bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', channel=channel_list[0], bitrate=500000, app_name='CANoe') . I have kept the same configuration.

Comment: In the link I have given, they are using a different class: can.interfaces.vector.VectorBus